# Cost of importing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-native, import

forgive my ignorance but I wish to understand something. Suppose I have 3 files and I import in all 3 like this

```
import React from "react"
import { View } from "react-native"
import lodash from "lodash"
import CustomComponent from "./path"
```

Will the 3 files create new instances of each imported code thereby using more memory or use the same instance.
If it creates them again in memory, what can I do to make sure it doesn't in my application.